# Application of Primary Key from Parent Table to Child Table

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-ce

I have the following tables in my SQL Server CE database:

**ORDERS**

```
OrderID (handled my DBMS)  
CustomerID  
OrderDate
```

**ORDER_DETAILS**

```
OrderID (from the ORDERS table)  
ProductID  
OrderQTY
```

I currently use 2 insert queries to add new orders to the database. The first one to inserts the order into the `ORDERS` table and allow the DBMS to create the `OrderID`, and the second one that uses that `OrderID` provided to insert to the `ORDER_DETAILS` table.

The approach I have used below seems very klunky and potentially vulnerable to concurrency issues. Is there a way to have the DBMS handle the creation of the correct `OrderID` for the `ORDER_DETAILS` table when a new record is inserted into the `ORDERS` table?

This is the C# I use to run the insert queries:

```
    public int InsertOrder(Order order)
    {
        DBConnection connection = DBConnection.getInstance();
        connection.conn.Open();
        using (SqlCeCommand query = new SqlCeCommand(OrderCommandList.cmdInsertOrderHeader, connection.conn))
        {
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", order.CustomerID);
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", order.OrderDate);
            query.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        //retrieves the PK for the recently inserted record
        int newOrderPK = 0;
         using(SqlCeCommand cmdGetIdentity = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", connection.conn))
         {
             newOrderPK = Convert.ToInt32(cmdGetIdentity.ExecuteScalar());
         }
         connection.conn.Close();
        InsertOrderDetails(order, newOrderPK);
        return newOrderPK;
    }

    //inserts all the order details associated with the Order object
    private void InsertOrderDetails(Order order, int orderForeignKey)
    {
        foreach (OrderDetail od in order.OrderLineItems)
        {
            DBConnection connection = DBConnection.getInstance();
            connection.conn.Open();
            using (SqlCeCommand query = new SqlCeCommand(OrderCommandList.cmdInsertOrderDetails, connection.conn))
            {
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", orderForeignKey);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", od.ProductID);
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderQty", od.QtyOrdered);
                query.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have this question tagged C# so it might be useful to know what C# code you're using at the moment to save the data.  It might have a bearing on the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your stored procedure to select the generated identity value, and have it use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();` rather than `SELECT @@IDENTITY;`. Actually, preferable would be to use an OUTPUT parameter, but for now I'll assume you're going to keep using `SELECT`. e.g.

```sql
INSERT dbo.Orders(CustomerID,OrderDate) SELECT @CustomerID,@OrderDate;
SELECT ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Then, instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` for the insert, then a separate command for the `SELECT @@IDENTITY`, you just need one `ExecuteScalar` to perform both.

You can do even better than this using TVPs, where you could send the order and all of the detail rows with a single stored procedure. However, CE is a little passé - not sure if it supports TVPs. You should consider using Express / LocalDB.

Comment: Scope_identity is not available with sql server compact, only option is @@identity, and it is important to issue the second select against the same open connection, and only a single statement is allowed per command